# How to know user created in AWS has what access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I Have users created in AWS, but I am not able to locate if they have been only given programmatic access or console access or they have been provided with both.

is there a way to check , edit, or know what type of access is being used by a user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the console, you can see it in the Security Credentials Tab of the User in IAM:
[image]

If the list of Access keys is not empty and at least one entry is active, it means they have programmatic access.

From the CLI you can also get this information. [Erik showed you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72053628/6485881) the command to list the access keys for a user to check if they have programmatic access.

```
$ aws iam list-access-keys --user-name raspi --no-cli-pager
{
    "AccessKeyMetadata": [
        {
            "UserName": "raspi",
            "AccessKeyId": "AKIA2BFBC12345KHW4",
            "Status": "Active",
            "CreateDate": "2021-07-07T07:42:37+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

To figure out if a user can log in to the console, you need to check if they have a login profile:

```sh
$ # This user can login
$ aws iam get-login-profile --user-name raspi --no-cli-pager
{
    "LoginProfile": {
        "UserName": "raspi",
        "CreateDate": "2021-07-07T07:42:37+00:00",
        "PasswordResetRequired": false
    }
}
$ # This user can't login to the console
$ aws iam get-login-profile --user-name ses-demo-sender --no-cli-pager

An error occurred (NoSuchEntity) when calling the GetLoginProfile operation: Login Profile for User ses-demo-sender cannot be found.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check If a user has access keys. If a user has programatic access it needs access keys.

Here is a Cli command:

```
aws iam list-access-keys --user-name Bob
```

Comment: Yes the user profile is something I was looking for , because a user can have both accesses at same time but my focus is for the users with only cli access and not console access. Thanks Maurice and Erik